# OrientDB 2.1 Exception in thread "OrientDB WAL Flush Task" with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (heap or GC)

Tags: java, out-of-memory, orientdb, heap-memory, wal

I'm doing a select using console.sh on OrientDB v.2.1. 
After waiting some minutes, I get the following output:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I have 6GB of RAM available and I'm using the default configurations.

I tried to uncomment JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024 changing the value to 4G, restart orientdb and run the query again...the result is:

```
Exception in thread "OrientDB WAL Flush Task (dati_scopus)" 
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

orientdb {db=dati_scopus}> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.addConditionWaiter(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1855)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2068)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I fix it to have a result?

**UPDATE:** same story using version 2.2 with default configuration

```
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: Hi @laro Do you have a lot of records? How many?

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi! I'm working with 3 classes (one cluster each) with A = 70272, B = 164889 and C = 49914 records. They are connected by lightweight edges and I'm using them to go from A to B to C and back 3 times (A->B->C->B->A x 3)

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap in the server.bat/server.sh ?

Comment: hi @AlessandroRota, I'm using only the console (console.sh) and not orientdb server (server.sh)...does the console.sh use the server.sh parameters? Right now in server.sh I have ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" (default)

Comment: Hi @laro what kind of select are you executing? Have you tried with an index?

Comment: Hi @laro if you don't launch the server.sh , console.sh don't use the server.sh parameters

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi From a specific record in A, let's say John, I use the edges to go from it to all the records in A (passing between B and C) that are connected with John (people who collaborated with John). I have no problem if I search for who direcly collaborated with John and indirectly with I'm at depht 1 and 2...if I go more deeper OrientDB does not give me a result

Comment: Can you write your query?

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi SELECT name FROM (SELECT expand(out('AuthorAfference').in('ArticleAfference').out('ArticleAfference').in('AuthorAfference').out('AuthorAfference').in('ArticleAfference').out('ArticleAfference').in('AuthorAfference').out('AuthorAfference').in('ArticleAfference').out('ArticleAfference').in('AuthorAfference').out('AuthorAfference').in('ArticleAfference').out('ArticleAfference').in('AuthorAfference')) FROM author where author_id='491' limit -1) GROUP BY author_id limit -1

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi authod_id with 491 is John, schema is author->AuthorAfference (LW edge)-> Afference -> ArticleAfference (LW edge) -> Article

Comment: Can you try to put an index NOTUNIQUE_HAS_INDEX on author_id?

Comment: @AlessandroRota k, I changed the java call in console.sh giving -Xms6g -Xmx6g. The configuration works and the JVM use a min and max heap of 6GB (I have a 6GB PC)..I don't have any error but neither a result after 30 minutes

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi running java with -Xms5g -Xmx6g and replacing the UNIQUE index with NOTUNIQUE_HAS_INDEX I have no result waiting 15 minutes (then I killed the process)

Comment: @Iaro are you sure that this query SELECT name FROM (SELECT expand(out('AuthorAfference').in('ArticleAfference')) FROM author where author_id='491' limit -1) GROUP BY author_id limit -1 give you some results ?

Comment: @AlessandroRota precisely, that one no because there name and author_id are not in the result. By the way, "SELECT expand(out('AuthorAfference').in('ArticleAfference')) FROM author where author_id='491' limit -1" gives results on which I can group by and do projections (properties of the class Article)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve OutOfMemoryError using OrientDB console change the heap min a max size.

Edit bin/console.sh changing the exec arguments. For example, to use a min of 5GB and max of 6GB use the following

```
exec "$JAVA" -Xms5g -Xmx6g -client $JAVA_OPTS $ORIENTDB_SETTINGS $SSL_OPTS
```

Be sure to remove in the SSL_OPTS parameter the Xmx values (or it will overwritten the previus Xmx given and showing an error if smaller than Xms)